# What generic collections in C# are IXmlSerializable?

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, collections

Are any of the .NET generic collections marked as IXmlSerializable? I've tried List<T> and Collection<T> but neither work out of the box.

Before I roll my own collection<T>, list<T>, or dictionary<T> class, I thought I'd check to see whether Microsoft had included something that does this already. It seems like basic functionality.

EDIT: By "rolling my own" I mean creating a class that inherits from a generic collection class and also implements IXmlSerializable. Here's one example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/IXmlSerializable.aspx. And here's another example: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx.

I'm using the DataContractSerializer within a method whose signature looks like this:

```
public static Stream GetXmlStream(IXmlSerializable item)
```

The problem is that while there are many classes in the .NET framework that are serializable, not all of them have explicitly implement the IXmlSerializable interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there aren't any. You could take a look at the attached link, though. I think you'll find it useful.

[Serialize and deserialize objects as Xml using generic types in C# 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20200204000600/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/paulwhitblog/archive/2007/07/20/114076.aspx)

Comment: This article you linked to shows how to use generics to perform serialization. I want a generic collection that can be serialized.

Answer (score 5):

There is no requirement to implement IXmlSerializable to **be** xml serializable.

```
public class Foo 
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
}
```

will xml serialize just fine producing something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Foo 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Names>
    <string>a</string>
    <string>b</string>
    <string>c</string>
  </Names>
</Foo>
```

whereas

```
public class Foo<T> 
{
    public List<T> Names {  get; set; }
}
```

will produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<FooOfString 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Names>
    <string>a</string>
    <string>b</string>
    <string>c</string>
  </Names>
</FooOfString>
```

Answer (score 2):

Related to your question, if you want to serialize/deserialize an IDictionary see [this useful post](http://www.mattberther.com/2004/06/14/serializing-an-idictionary-object/). I'd use the pattern shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable) for your read and write methods though, as they deal better with different situations.

Comment: That's a great link. I wound up doing something very similar. +1

Comment: Also see the second link i added. I had some problems with the code on the first one, particularly if the collection is empty...

Answer (score 1):

After some further research on my own, I came to the same conclusion. None of the .NET generic collections are IXmlSerializable as of .NET 3.5 SP1.