# .NET XmlIgnore By Default?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Is there a way to have XmlSerializer ignore all members by default, unless I say otherwise?

I have a base class and several derived classes with lots of members, but most I do not want to be serialized. Only a select few are acceptable for serialization.

Comment: No. There is no way to do this. Why are you using XML Serialization? What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: .NET 3.5. I am using XML files to describe cutscenes in a game. I'd like those XML files deserialized into corresponding classes/objects so the game engine can run the cutscene. There will also be re-serialization in the cutscene editor. If there's a better way to do this than XML, I'm open to suggestions. XML+XMLSerializer makes it easy to modify and debug cutscenes by hand, but also easy to implement and work with in the C# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do this.

The XmlSerializer is using a "opt-out" process - it will serialize everything (all public properties) unless you explicitly opt-out by using the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute. There's no way of changing this behavior.

The .NET 3.5 DataContractSerializer on the other hand is taking the other approach - opt-in. It will not serialize anything, unless you specifically tell it to, by decorating your members with `[DataMember]`.

So maybe the DataContract serializer would work for you? It was a few more advantages (doesn't require a parameter-less constructor, can serialize internal and private properties, too, and it can also serialize fields instead of properties, if needed), and it's tuned for speed. There's some downsides, too - it doesn't support attributes in XML nodes - so you'll have to pick based on your requirements.

There's a good comparison of the two by [Dan Rigsby](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/) - check it out!

Marc

Comment: A make-or-break factor might be the fact that DataContractSerializer does not support XmlAttributeAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [IXMLSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and determine what you want to be serialized. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx) is an example of Object serialization.  Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable) SO post about the proper way to implement IXMLSerializable. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/IXmlSerializable.aspx?msg=3057342) is an example of IXMLSerializable using for some collections.

It would look something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplicationCSharp
{
  public class ObjectToSerialize : IXmlSerializable
  {
    public string Value1;
    public string Value2;
    public string Value3;   
    public string ValueToSerialize;
    public string Value4;
    public string Value5;

    public ObjectToSerialize() { }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
      writer.WriteElementString("Val", ValueToSerialize);
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader) 
    {
        if (reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "Event")
        {
            ValueToSerialize = reader["Val"];
            reader.Read();
        }        
    }
    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return (null); }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ObjectToSerialize t = new ObjectToSerialize();
      t. ValueToSerialize= "Hello";
      System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectToSerialize));
      x.Serialize(Console.Out, t);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I thnk writer.WriteFullEndElement(); is not needed in your code, since you have used WriteElementString instead of WriteStartElement.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it.  I guess I should also note I was being a bit lazy, this class wouldnt xml serialize to anything since I dont have any properties.  Lets assume my member variables are properties :)