# How to seralize only some properties in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

This is for a web project so i have several classes that inherit from Web.UI.

I only want to serialize very particular properties (basically, only local properties)

I'm aware of the XMLIgnore property that can be placed on a property to ignore items, but this won't work in my context since that would require modifying a bunch of stuff that i really don't want to modify (and probably can't).

So how do i tell the xml serializer to ignore everything except for X and Y or tell it to seralize just X and Y?

i could just create my own xml in a string builder or something and if that's the only way, so be it. however i'm looking for a method that will employ the built in XML stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Custom Serialization, you can derive your class from [**ISerializable**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) Interface and provide Custom Serialization accordingly

Comment: That works perfect. Thanks to you and Si. 
Now just have to figure out how to get it to not add the default opening element (class name)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you implement [IXmlSerializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable)?

Answer (score 0):

You could put some hack into it and simply tear stuff out of the XML after it comes back.

It's a terrible idea compared to XMLIgnore, which is the correct solution, but you could certainly pull up the XML, spin through it, and remove whatever you don't want to see.

Sometimes terrible ideas are the best ones.