# c# deserialize xml with a specified 'encoding' and 'stylesheet' lines

Tags: c#, serialization

I am creating an XML file using the System.Xml.Serialization module.
I have a class that gets serialized into an XML file. The file looks like this:

```
<itemList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <itemListed>
    <item ID="81288" Synopsys="Reset search point" CompletedTime="7/27/10 4:12 PM" Resolver="owner1" />
    <item ID="81285" Synopsys="Added contructor" CompletedTime="6/05/10 9:23 AM" Resolver="owner2" />
  </itemListed>
</itemList>
```

Problem is,  I would like it to generate this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="item.xsl"?>
  <itemListed>
    <item ID="81288" Synopsys="Reset search point" CompletedTime="7/27/10 4:12 PM" Resolver="owner1" />
    <item ID="81285" Synopsys="Added contructor" CompletedTime="6/05/10 9:23 AM" Resolver="owner2" />
  </itemListed>
```

Any idea what I need to change to my class?

My code:

`public class Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }`

```
    [XmlAttribute("Synopsys")]
    public string Synopsys { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("CompletedTime")]
    public string CompletedTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Resolver")]
    public string Resolver { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "itemListed")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "item")]
    public List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

I appreciate any help.
Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found an easy way to customize the stylesheet or the encoding line but I found a good suggestion here:

[link text](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/WriteXmlWithStyle.aspx)

The idea is to pretty much write your own serialization class.  I took the idea from the article and I created a class that serializes the class (using the C# library) then a filter modifies the header to modify the encoding line and add the stylesheet line.
When I load the xml, I read the file, I pass it through the filter to remove the stylesheet line and I change back the encoding line.  Once I have done that, I use the de-serializer provided by C#. 
It seems to work.

Tony

Answer (score -1):

One solution might be to implement IXmlSerializable interface on your class.  I'm not sure if the XmlWriter will allow you to write a XML tag or not.  [Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I think I found and easier way to deal with the problem.
Tony

Comment: Can you post what your answer was and mark it as the answer?  I'm interested in what you came up with.