# Extend .NET XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net

The question is simple as stated in the title.

I need to somehow extend the existing .NET XMLSerializer.

The reasons are

- It already does so many things. I do not want to reinvent the wheel.
- I need to deserialize a bunch of tags to a key/value pair. E.g.

```
<City>
    <Suburb1>Test1</Suburb1>
    <Suburb2>Test2</Suburb2>
</City>
```

This needs to be deserialized to

```
    `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>` suburbsList
     `suburbsList.Add(new KeyValuePair("Suburb1", "Test1"))
     `suburbsList.Add(new KeyValuePair("Suburb2", "Test2"))
```

The example here is simplified, so having strongly typed properties is not an option.

I tried `UnknownNode` event from the `XmlSerializer` class but it does not seem to do what I'm intending. TBH, I have not explored a lot on this though.

Comment: A list of kvps is kind of weird to me, but can you do something like this to get your output?

`XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(xml);
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nodes = (from node in document.SelectSingleNode("/City")?.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()
                                            select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(node.Name, node.InnerText ?? "")).ToList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use XmlDocument. That's slow for large documents.

Comment: Got it, wasn’t exactly sure what the size of your data source was so I’d figure asking first. Is your XML coming in as a stream?

Comment: Yes, it's a stream.