# Serialize elements of an array but not the array (XMLSerizlization)

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a simple array that I need to serialize as part of a larger object.

```
public class Holder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Thing[] Thingies { get; set; }
}

public class Thing {}
```

Normally this would be serialized as:

```
...
<Holder>
    <ID>...</ID>
    <Name>...</Name>
    <ArrayOfThing>
        <Thing>...</Thing>
        <Thing>...</Thing>
        <Thing>...</Thing>
        ...
    </ArrayOfThing>
</Holder>
```

Without worrying too much about deserialization, is there a way I could simply remove the ArrayOf element, but keep the elements inside, so that I'd have:

```
...
<Holder>
    <ID>...</ID>
    <Name>...</Name>
    <Thing>...</Thing>
    <Thing>...</Thing>
    <Thing>...</Thing>
    ...
</Holder>
```

Comment: Will `Holder` only have the array of `Things`?

Comment: @Austin No, it would have other elements. Let me update the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
public class Holder
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Thing")]
    public Thing[] Thingies { get; set; }
}
```

[MSDN for XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) has some examples as well.

Comment: Wouldn't that just wrap Thing in another Thing tag?

Comment: @MPelletier nope. look at the example in the linked msdn page or just give it a try.

Comment: OK, I thought XmlElement was a way to rename the tag. Silly me. I haven't actually seen it in action. I'll check the page AND try it. :)

Comment: Wow, it renames the tag in every other context, but with arrays, it just renames the elements, not the array! Nice! Now to read up!

Answer (score 0):

You could implement IXmlSerializable to let you read and write Thing or other children from the containing XML element.

Here is how you would implement this [Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[XmlElement]` attribute:

```
[XmlElement]
public Thing[] Thingies { get; set; }
```