# Good way to serialize any custom WCF SecurityToken?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xml-serialization, wcf-security

This is making me crazy... I'm trying to have a custom WCF auth token that derives from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken` for example:

```
    public class TestSecurityToken : SecurityToken
    {
        public override string Id
        { get { return "123"; } }

        public override ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityKey> SecurityKeys
        { get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityKey>(new List<SecurityKey>(0)); } }

        public override DateTime ValidFrom
        { get { return DateTime.MinValue; } }

        public override DateTime ValidTo
        {get { return DateTime.MaxValue; } }

        public string Property1 { get; set; }
    }
```

I know I can write a custom serializer for it that extends `WSSecurityTokenSerializer`, but I am trying to find a way to do that in a generic way, where I can make a serializer that can serialize any `<T> where T : SecurityToken`

Here is what I have tried, and failed:

---

**Attempt 1**: Make the SecurityToken a DataContract

```
[DataContract]
public class TestSecurityToken : SecurityToken
```

Fails because you cant have a DataContract that derives from a base class that isn't a DataContract, which SecurityToken is not.

---

**Attempt 2**: Serialize with an XmlSerializer

```
public class SecurityTokenSerializer<T> : WSSecurityTokenSerializer where T : SecurityToken
{
    private readonly XmlSerializer serializer;

    public SecurityTokenSerializer()
    {
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
    }

    protected override void WriteTokenCore(XmlWriter writer, SecurityToken token)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, token);
    }
```

This fails with the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'PartsSource.Services.Core.ServiceModel.SecurityTokenSerializerTest.TestSecurityToken'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: To be XML serializable, types which inherit from ICollection must have an implementation of Add(System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy. System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[[System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] does not implement Add(System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityKey).

Due to this property on my custom `SecurityToken`:

```
        public override ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityKey> SecurityKeys
        { get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityKey>(new List<SecurityKey>(0)); } }
```

---

**Attempt 3**: Same as above, but try to tell the XmlSerializer to ignore that SecurityKeys property:

```
public class SecurityTokenSerializer<T> : WSSecurityTokenSerializer where T : SecurityToken
{
    private readonly XmlSerializer serializer;

    public SecurityTokenSerializer()
    {
        var xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        xOver.Add(typeof(T), "SecurityKeys", new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true });
        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T), xOver);
    }
```

This errors with the same message as the previous attempt. It does not ignore this property.

---

Does anyone have any other ideas on how to just serialize any SecurityToken to an XmlReader / XmlWriter? It seems like it should have been dead simple, but no...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found no other good way to do this, what I ended up doing was making my custom SecurityToken also implement `IXmlSerializable`, and then changed the definition of my serializer to:

```
public class SecurityTokenSerializer<T> : WSSecurityTokenSerializer
    where T : SecurityToken, IXmlSerializable
```

My custom security token is then defined as:

```
public class MySecurityToken : SecurityToken, IXmlSerializable
```

Then the serializer can delegate serialization to the custom security token. It probably isn't the cleanest solution (I'd say it violates the single-responsibility principal), but it does seem to work and let me not have to write a serializer for every custom token.

Comment: Please can you put an example of code of how the Serializable works on MySecurityToken? @CodingWithSpike

Comment: @Zinov.  You can find those anywhere..that problem isn't specific to SecurityTokens.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable

Comment: Can you show your serialization code?  I mimicked you, but got same error (The token Serializer cannot serialize 'TestSecurityToken '.  If this is a custom type you must supply a custom serializer.) .. (start code after this)  XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings(); /**/
xws.Indent = false; /**/
xws.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None; /**/
/**/
SecurityTokenSerializer<TestSecurityToken> ser = new SecurityTokenSerializer<TestSecurityToken>();/**/
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\temp\myfile.xml", xws))/**/
{
 ser.WriteToken(xw, myToken);/**/
}