# XML with collections and XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, collections, xsd, xmlserializer

I have an XSD:

```
<xs:complexType name="rootType">    
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="foo" type="fooType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="bar" type="barType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>    
</xs:complexType>
<!-- SKIPPED -->
<xs:element name="root" type="rootType"></xs:element>
```

I have an XML built using this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <foo><!-- SKIPPED --></foo>
  <foo><!-- SKIPPED --></foo>
  <foo><!-- SKIPPED --></foo>
  <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
  <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
  <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
  <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
</root>
```

Now I want to serialize/deserialize this XML using XmlSerializer.
I have C# classes:

```
public class fooType
{
    public string element { get; set; }
}

public class barType
{
    public string element { get; set; }
}

public class rootType
{
    public fooType[] foos { get; set; }
    public barType[] bars { get; set; }
}
```

There were some XML-related attributes, like XmlElementAttribute, but I omit them in example above for simplicity.

Now please take a look at `rootType` class definition. Here we have two properties `foos` and `bars`. They will be serialized like root elements for `fooType[]` and `barType[]` arrays:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <foos>
    <foo><!-- SKIPPED --></foo>
    <foo><!-- SKIPPED --></foo>
    <foo><!-- SKIPPED --></foo>
  </foos>
  <bars>
    <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
    <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
    <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
    <bar><!-- SKIPPED --></bar>
  </bars>
</root>
```

But this is not what I want. How to serialize them according to XSD and example at the beginning of this post?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your criteria, I would Implement `IXmlSerializable` on `rootType`.  There is a great read here on SO on how to create the XML you are looking for.

[Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable)

Answer (score 1):

I find that the quickest way of working out how to design your classes to match a specific schema is to run the `xsd.exe` tool backwards. Tell it to generate classes from your schema, and compare them with your hand-written classes to see where you went wrong. It's a great way of gaining experience in how the serializer works.