# custom XML serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I need to serialize my entities. I using LinqToSql as ORM. 
I don't want to mark all fields and class with attributes.
Is there custom library for xml serializtion without attributes( at least not required) and support collections?

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box xml serilization should work

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about libraries but you can always do a [Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable) This will allow you to *MANUALLY* create XML exactly as you need it.