# How to customize the xml using xmlserializer in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class DisplayFunction 
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
        public byte[] Color
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
        public FunctionShape Shape
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute()]
        public int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

I am using xml serializer and getting the result:

```
<DisplayFunctions Color="et57hQ==" Shape="Bar" Id="514" />
```

while i want the result to be:

```
 <DisplayFunctions Color="122,222,123,133" Shape="Bar" Id="514" />
```

How can I get that result ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075860/c-sharp-custom-xml-serialization, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109827/custom-xml-serialization, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292084/custom-xml-serialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML serializer is serializing the Color using byte array. So the result is odd.

My suggesting is using a public property of type `string` to serialize the color, and then use a conversion to convert colors to strings and vice versa.

```
string HtmlColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(MyColorInstance);
string HtmlColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(MyColorInstance);
```

So, you need the following:

```
  Color mColor;
  [XmlIgnore]
  public Color Color
  {
      get { return mColor; }
      set { mColor = value; }
  }

  [XmlElement("Color")]
  public string ColorStr
  {
      get { return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color); }
      set { Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(value); }
  }
```

**Note**: If you need to convert the `Color` to a `byte[]` you can add an additional property to get the color as a `byte[]` also ignoring with `[XmlIgnore]` attribute.

If the format provided by the `ColorTranslator.ToHtml` is not valid for you, you can use a custom Color translation, for example

```
public string ToCustomString(Color color)
{
    return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

And a similar method for for parsign a color from string.

Hope it helps-