# C# XML Serialization of multiple objects of the same type within a single tag

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following XML that I would like to reproduce using xml serialization:

```
<Room>
<!-- One light-->  
<light Type="Incadenscent" fin="QS f" ItemType="something "/>
<!-- Unlimited Tables -->
<table Type="BR" Id="10"/>
<table Type="BL" Id="21"/>
<table Type="BR" Id="22"/>
<table Type="GR" Id="35"/>
<table Type="BR" Id="18"/>
<table Type="RE" Id="55"/>
</Room>
```

Below are my object types:

```
public class Table
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public String Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

}

public class Light
{

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("fin")]
    public string FIN
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("ItemType")]
    public string ItemType
    {
        get; set;
    }
 }

public class Room{

      public Table Table
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public Light Light
    {
        get; set;
    }

  }

 public  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Room> list = new List<Room>
        {
            new Room
            {

                Light = new Light{ Type="Incadenscent",  fin="QS", ItemType="something"},
                Table = new Table{Type="Metal", Id="10"}
                //error here when I try to add a new table object
                Table = new Table{Type="Wood", Id="13"}
            }
           } ;     
         SerializeToXML(list);

    }
    static public void SerializeToXML(List<Room> sample) 
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Room>)););
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\assets.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, sample);
        textWriter.Close();

    }
}
```

I get an error(specifically-duplication of object) when I try to instantiate another table object within the Room object. What am I doing wrong?

for example:

```
                **Table = new Table{Type="Wood", Id="13"}**
```

How can I instantiate another table object in the room list without getting a duplication error

Comment: You have one light and one table per room so, to add another table, you need another room.

Comment: How can I instantiate another table object in the room list without getting a duplication error?

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple solution for that:

```
public class Room
{
     [XmlElement("light")]
     public Light Light { get; set; }
     [XmlElement("table")]
     public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

The initialization is as described by @HackedByChinese's answer.

Declare the List as [XmlElement], then it will not serialize the <tables> element, and the xml will look exactly like you want.

Comment: +1 Derp. I forgot about `XmlElement`'s effect on collections.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't match the class. `Room` declares that it contains one `Light` and one `Table`, where the XML has multiple `Tables`.

`Room` should look more like:

```
public class Room
{
     public Light Light { get; set; }
     public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}
```

and create the object like this:

```
    new Room
    {

        Light = new Light{ Type="Incadenscent",  fin="QS", ItemType="something"},
        Tables = new List<Table>{ new Table{Type="Metal", Id="10"},
                                  new Table{Type="Wood", Id="13"} }
    }
```

However, you still will have deserialization problems. XmlSerializer will expect the XML to look more like:

```
<Room>
    <light Type="Incadenscent" fin="QS f" ItemType="something "/>
    <tables>
       <table Type="BR" Id="10"/>
       <table Type="BL" Id="21"/>
       <table Type="BR" Id="22"/>
       <table Type="GR" Id="35"/>
       <table Type="BR" Id="18"/>
       <table Type="RE" Id="55"/>
     </tables>
</Room>
```

However, if the resulting XML *must* look the way you specified in your example, you will need to [implement `IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable) on `Table`, and use the `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` to deserialize and serialize (respectively) manually.