# E pluribus unum: merge objects into one

Tags: c#, .net

I have a predefined data format, which requires me to have an object like this:

```
settings:{
    settingA:'someValueFromSql',
    settingB:'someValueFromAD'
    settingC:'someValueFromConfigFile',
    settingD:'someValueFromReflection',
    settingE:42,
    ...
}
```

This `settings` object is in fact a huge mess of data stitched together from many different sources, but this is how the data is expected by the frontend. I'd like to put the "get/process all data from one source" in a function each, and tape the object together in the end.

So I would have one object

```
sqlSettings:{
    settingA:'someValueFromSql',
    settingG:'someOtherValueFromSql',
    ...
}
```

returned by function a, and an object

```
adSettings:{
    settingB:'someValueFromAD',
    settingV:'someOtherValueFromAD',
    ...
}
```

returned by function b, and an object

```
settings includes adSettings, sqlSettings
```

where, with at most two simple steps, I can "join together" both objects into a flat third object.

Is this possible with fixed-size objects, without using a generic Dictionary, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

(I'm sure this question was already asked on SO, but I guess I don't find the right words)

Comment: +1 For someone at last writing some Latin I can read!

Comment: Except it's **E** pluribus unum. And you should also at least know Deus ex machina, quod erat demonstrandum, id est, and exempli gratia :-)

Comment: Monthy Python's life of brian all over again

Comment: Yep, it is: [E Pluribus Unum](http://i48.tinypic.com/2nw1yiq.png)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Everyone knows `Quo errat demonstrator`...

Comment: Wow. So comments. Much useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible with a "normal" object, but you can do it with an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [dynamic keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx). But you need at least .net 4.0

```
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
//If you try to assign a property that doesn't exist, it is added to the object.
settings.SettingA="sfgd"
```

Anyway I discourage using this approach. why you don't want to use a `IDictionary<string, object>` or better a `IDictionary<string, MyCustomSettingObject>`

--------------------UPDATE---------------------

if the only thing that stops you from using a dictionary is the serialization you can implement the [IXmlSerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) and ouput the xml you like:

[Proper way to implement IXmlSerializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable)

Comment: I also do not recommend using the dynamic object, but good point, I have completely forgotten about it.

Comment: As to "why don't I want to use a IDictionary", it is because the XML tree of an IDictionary is so awful. Should we ever change from JSON to XML for any reason, I'd like to have everything neat and tidy.

Comment: @Alexander I know it is a long way but you can implement your custom serialization..

Comment: What's to stop you writing a custom XML serialization method for your dictionary? It's a trivial process.

Comment: @NickUdell not so trivial for a dictionary but IMHO is better to take this road instead of dynamics

Answer (score 1):

If those partial setting objects have fixed size (meaning fixed number of properties), then you can definitely create a flat object with e.g. only properties to fit all the values in. Then to ease your work, you can try to use Automapper to map the partial objects to the "grouped" object.

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Otherwise, you will have to stick with the dictionary.