# C# [anonymous\generic] object to byte[] without BinaryFormatter [in .NET 4.5]?

Tags: c#, serialization, portable-class-library, binaryformatter, binarywriter

`BinaryFormatter` works great, but doesn't exist in Portable class libraries for .NET 4.5.

> I've read that it IS in .NET 4.6 Portable. I have not confirmed this
>   because when I change to 4.6 in my project settings, I get a warning
>   message that "4.5 will be automatically targeted" unless I de-select
>   Silverlight, WindowsPhone, Windows Universal, Xamarin, etc), so I can only target .NET 4.6 Portable if I'm NOT targeting additional platforms, thus defeating the purpose.

Here is my original BinarySerializer (Works but NOT PCL because uses `BinaryFormatter`)

```
private string BinarySerialize(object Source)
{
    byte[] serializedObject;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, Source);
        serializedObject = stream.ToArray();
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(serializedObject);
}
```

So, that being said, I started trying to re-write my BinarySerializer to use `BinaryReader` and `BinaryWriter` which are both available in PCL, and ran into the following issues:

`BinaryWriter`, can only handle simple types (like `string`, `bool`, `byte`, `long`, `int`, etc) and `Streams`, so think I need to find a way to convert anonymous objects to a `Stream`.

Am I on the right path? How do you convert types which are not known until runtime (like a `System.Delegate` - and yes I know serializing delegates produces brittle code) or anonymouse\generic types to their equivalent byte array `byte[]`? Is there a way to convert an object directly to a `Stream` or `MemoryStream`?

If this is not possible at all, how would you recommend I write an `interface` for my BinarySerializer, so I can implement the functionality in my portable class library while the actual `BinaryFormatter` classes implementing the `interface` exists in platform-specific assemblies?

FYI, this is an MVVM project in which "Serializers" are considered Models deriving from a `ValueConverter` abstract base class. Serialization is only used to transport instantiated tasks to their destination for execution.

Comment: Why are you serializing anyway?  And what do you expect serializing a delegate to do for you?  Delegates are mostly about _code_, which is not serialized.

Comment: I'm theorizing a rule-builder interface which builds Serializable `Conditions` that can later be deserialized and executed against a dataset. I'm trying to allow custom (typed) rules (any `Func<dataTypeT,bool>`) as well as allowing `Func<dataTypeT>` to exist in place of actual `dataTypeT` in the `Condition`'s parameters.Thanks

Comment: Well, you can't serialize methods (at least not using the methods you are using now) so I'm not sure that your design will work.

Comment: BinaryFormatter can serialize just about anything, including static Delegates, Actions and Functions, to a byte[]. The only issue is that BinaryFormatter does not exist in Portable .NET 4.5

Comment: BinaryFormatter is also notorious for creating versioning issues, if you later add new things to the types then the BinaryFormatter class likely won't deserialize your data any more. Binary serialization is meant as a *transport* format, not as a *storage* format.

Comment: Thanks, @LasseV.Karlsen thats exactly what I need, to use this as a universal transport format in order to ship "task building" commands to their destination (one machine\app\service to another), and execute them under predefined conditions (delegates).

Comment: `BinaryFormatter` is *not* supported in the Portable Class Library (per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter), which omits any mention) and likely never will be, because it supports the remoting infrastructure, and remoting as a whole is considered deprecated (except across AppDomains, but that's also outside the scope of the PCL). There are some [independent efforts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620154/UniversalSerializer), though.