# How to serialize an ICollection<T> that also has read/write properties to XML

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have class that implement list of custom class. That class also has two properties. But when I serialize that class, XML contains only array of my custom classes but don't contains another two properties. 
Here is the class:

```
public class Porudzbina : List<PorudzbenicaStavka>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    public long KomSifra { get; set; }
    public Guid KomId { get; set; }

    IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        var sqlRow = new SqlDataRecord(
              new SqlMetaData("rb", SqlDbType.Int),
              new SqlMetaData("RobaSifra", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50),
              new SqlMetaData("RobaNaziv", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
             );
        foreach (PorudzbenicaStavka por in this)
        {
            sqlRow.SetInt32(0, por.rb);
            sqlRow.SetString(1, por.RobaSifra);
            sqlRow.SetString(2, por.RobaNaziv);
            yield return sqlRow;
        }
    }
}
```

and code that I use to serialize it:

```
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Porudzbina));
    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xmle.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, por);
    }
```

and this is XML that I got:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPorudzbenicaStavka xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <PorudzbenicaStavka>
    <rb>1</rb>
    <RobaSifra>3702</RobaSifra>
    <RobaNaziv>Foullon mlecna cokolada 33% Ecuador 100g</RobaNaziv>    
  </PorudzbenicaStavka>
  <PorudzbenicaStavka>
    <rb>2</rb>
    <RobaSifra>1182</RobaSifra>
    <RobaNaziv>IL Capitano zelena maslina sa paprikom 720g</RobaNaziv>    
  </PorudzbenicaStavka>
  <PorudzbenicaStavka>
    <rb>3</rb>
    <RobaSifra>1120</RobaSifra>
    <RobaNaziv>Kaiser tuna steak sa papricicom u ulju 170g.</RobaNaziv>    
  </PorudzbenicaStavka>
</ArrayOfPorudzbenicaStavka>
```

I want my xml contains two properties together with a array of custom class, that I could deserialize it into its original state...

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your properties are not deserialized is explained in the documentation section [Serializing a Class that Implements the ICollection Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You can create your own collection classes by implementing the ICollection interface, and use the XmlSerializer to serialize instances of these classes. Note that when a class implements the ICollection interface, only the collection contained by the class is serialized. **Any public properties or fields added to the class will not be serialized.**

So, that's that.

You might consider changing your design so your classes do not have properties.  For some reasons to make this change, see [Why not inherit from List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt).

If you nevertheless choose to have a collection with serializable properties, you're going to need to [manually implement `IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable).  This is burdensome, since you need to handle many "edge" cases including empty elements, unexpected elements, comments, and presence or absence of whitespace, all of which can throw off your `ReadXml()` method.  For some background, see [How to Implement IXmlSerializable Correctly](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43237/How-to-Implement-IXmlSerializable-Correctly).

First, create a base class for generic lists with serializable properties:

```
public class XmlSerializableList<T> : List<T>, IXmlSerializable where T : new()
{
    public XmlSerializableList() : base() { }

    public XmlSerializableList(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }

    public XmlSerializableList(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }

    #region IXmlSerializable Members

    const string CollectionItemsName = "Items";
    const string CollectionPropertiesName = "Properties";

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // Do not write the wrapper element.

        // Serialize the collection.
        WriteCollectionElements(writer);

        // Serialize custom properties.
        writer.WriteStartElement(CollectionPropertiesName);
        WriteCustomElements(writer);
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        // Do not end the wrapper element.
    }

    private void WriteCollectionElements(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (Count < 1)
            return;
        // Serialize the collection.
        writer.WriteStartElement(CollectionItemsName);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", ""); // Disable the xmlns:xsi and xmlns:xsd lines.
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, item, ns);
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Write ALL custom elements to the XmlReader
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer"></param>
    protected virtual void WriteCustomElements(XmlWriter writer)
    {
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            reader.Read();
            return;
        }
        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Advance to the first sub element of the wrapper element.
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element)
                // Comment, whitespace
                reader.Read();
            else if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                reader.Read();
            else if (reader.Name == CollectionItemsName)
                ReadCollectionElements(reader);
            else if (reader.Name == CollectionPropertiesName)
                ReadCustomElements(reader);
            else
                // Unknown element, skip it.
                reader.Skip();
        }

        // Move past the end of the wrapper element
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    void ReadCustomElements(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Advance to the first sub element of the collection element.
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    while (subReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) // Read past XmlNodeType.None
                        if (!subReader.Read())
                            break;
                    ReadCustomElement(subReader);
                }
            }
            reader.Read();
        }
        // Move past the end of the properties element
        reader.Read();
    }

    void ReadCollectionElements(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        reader.ReadStartElement(); // Advance to the first sub element of the collection element.
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                using (var subReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
                {
                    while (subReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) // Read past XmlNodeType.None
                        if (!subReader.Read())
                            break;
                    var item = (T)serializer.Deserialize(subReader);
                    Add(item);
                }
            }
            reader.Read();
        }
        // Move past the end of the collection element
        reader.Read();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read ONE custom element from the XmlReader
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader"></param>
    protected virtual void ReadCustomElement(XmlReader reader)
    {
    }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

To use this class, you will need to override `ReadCustomElement(XmlReader reader)`, which reads a **single** custom property, and `WriteCustomElements(XmlWriter writer)`, which writes **all** custom properties.  (Note the asymmetry, it makes implementing class hierarchies a little easier.)  Then create your `Porudzbina` class as follows:

```
public class Porudzbina : XmlSerializableList<PorudzbenicaStavka>
{
    public long KomSifra { get; set; }
    public Guid KomId { get; set; }

    const string KomSifraName = "KomSifra";
    const string KomIdName = "KomId";

    protected override void WriteCustomElements(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(KomSifraName, XmlConvert.ToString(KomSifra));
        writer.WriteElementString(KomIdName, XmlConvert.ToString(KomId));
        base.WriteCustomElements(writer);
    }

    protected override void ReadCustomElement(XmlReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.Name == KomSifraName)
        {
            KomSifra = reader.ReadElementContentAsLong();
        }
        else if (reader.Name == KomIdName)
        {
            var s = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
            KomId = XmlConvert.ToGuid(s);
        }
        else
        {
            base.ReadCustomElement(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

This will create XML that looks like:

> ```
> <Porudzbina>
>     <Items>
>         <PorudzbenicaStavka>
>             <!-- contents of first PorudzbenicaStavka -->
>         </PorudzbenicaStavka>
>         <!-- Additional PorudzbenicaStavka -->
>     </Items>
>     <Properties>
>         <KomSifra>101</KomSifra>
>         <KomId>bb23a3b8-23d3-4edd-848b-d7621e6ed2c0</KomId>
>     </Properties>
> </Porudzbina>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I've uploaded my serialization library to Github, where such issues are handled.

[Atlas Xml Serializer](https://github.com/Atlas-Project/AtlasXmlSerializer)

I'm assuming that you have below data classes. I've just added [XmlElement] attribute over properties to force them serialize into xml elements.

```
public class Porudzbina : List<PorudzbenicaStavka>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    [XmlElement]
    public long KomSifra { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public Guid KomId { get; set; }

    IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        var sqlRow = new SqlDataRecord(
              new SqlMetaData("rb", SqlDbType.Int),
              new SqlMetaData("RobaSifra", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50),
              new SqlMetaData("RobaNaziv", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)
             );
        foreach (PorudzbenicaStavka por in this)
        {
            sqlRow.SetInt32(0, por.rb);
            sqlRow.SetString(1, por.RobaSifra);
            sqlRow.SetString(2, por.RobaNaziv);
            yield return sqlRow;
        }
    }
}

public class PorudzbenicaStavka
{
    [XmlElement]
    public int rb { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string RobaSifra { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string RobaNaziv { get; set;  }
}
```

And here's the instance:

```
var o = new Porudzbina
{
    new PorudzbenicaStavka { rb=1, RobaSifra="3702", RobaNaziv="Foullon mlecna cokolada 33% Ecuador 100g" },
    new PorudzbenicaStavka { rb=2, RobaSifra="1182", RobaNaziv="IL Capitano zelena maslina sa paprikom 720g" },
    new PorudzbenicaStavka { rb=3, RobaSifra="1120", RobaNaziv="Kaiser tuna steak sa papricicom u ulju 170g." },
};

o.KomId = new Guid("{EC63AEC3-1512-451F-B967-836DD0E9820A}");
o.KomSifra = 999999;
```

And here's how atlas xml serialization library does the job:

```
var serialized = Atlas.Xml.Serializer.Serialize(o, true);
var deserialized = Atlas.Xml.Serializer.Deserialize<Porudzbina>(serialized);
```

Xml would look like this:

```
<Porudzbina>
  <KomSifra>999999</KomSifra>
  <KomId>ec63aec3-1512-451f-b967-836dd0e9820a</KomId>
  <item>
    <rb>1</rb>
    <RobaSifra>3702</RobaSifra>
    <RobaNaziv>Foullon mlecna cokolada 33% Ecuador 100g</RobaNaziv>
  </item>
  <item>
    <rb>2</rb>
    <RobaSifra>1182</RobaSifra>
    <RobaNaziv>IL Capitano zelena maslina sa paprikom 720g</RobaNaziv>
  </item>
  <item>
    <rb>3</rb>
    <RobaSifra>1120</RobaSifra>
    <RobaNaziv>Kaiser tuna steak sa papricicom u ulju 170g.</RobaNaziv>
  </item>
</Porudzbina>
```

---

If you change the data class like this:

```
[Atlas.Xml.XmlSerializationType(ChildElementName = "PorudzbenicaStavka")]
public class Porudzbina : List<PorudzbenicaStavka>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    public long KomSifra { get; set; }
    public Guid KomId { get; set; }
    // ...
}

public class PorudzbenicaStavka
{
    public int rb { get; set; }
    public string RobaSifra { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string RobaNaziv { get; set;  }
}
```

Then, serialized class would be like this:

```
<Porudzbina KomSifra="999999" KomId="ec63aec3-1512-451f-b967-836dd0e9820a">
  <PorudzbenicaStavka rb="1" RobaSifra="3702">Foullon mlecna cokolada 33% Ecuador 100g</PorudzbenicaStavka>
  <PorudzbenicaStavka rb="2" RobaSifra="1182">IL Capitano zelena maslina sa paprikom 720g</PorudzbenicaStavka>
  <PorudzbenicaStavka rb="3" RobaSifra="1120">Kaiser tuna steak sa papricicom u ulju 170g.</PorudzbenicaStavka>
</Porudzbina>
```