# Newtonsoft's JSON.NET dont serialize Properties of `IEnumerable` types

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, ienumerable

### The problem

I am using JSON.NET to serialize complex model, and i encountered a situation where my Deserialized object Unequal to the Serialized one.

this situation caused by the way JSON.NET handle IEnumerable types,

When JSON.NET encounters a IEnumerable type, it takes it as a simple Array,
leaving out all other Properties aside.
Even when using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All` the fields are still neglected from the Wrapping JSON object.

### Minimal Reproduction Example:

```
public class MyModel : List<string>
{
  public MyModel(string id) 
  { 
    Id = id; 
    Add("hello");
    Add("world");
  }

  public string Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Deserialize the following class (with `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All`)
produce :

```
{
  "$type": "...MyModel[], ...",
  "$values": [
    "hello", 
    "world"
  ]
}
```

**Notice Leaving property `Id` out of the Serialization string.**

.

### Workaround:

For now, i just translated all my types to NOT be IEnumerable, but instead contain the base class as a member.

e.g.

```
public class MyModel
{
  public List<string> Values { get; private set; }
  public MyModel(string id) 
  { 
    Values = new List<string>();
    Id = id; 
    Values.Add("hello");
    Values.Add("world");
  }

  public string Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Though, for my model, this workaround is somewhat acceptable...
This serialization is destined to spread across more models then mine,
and I don't want to "forbid" model features (such as `IEnumerable`) from the models.

-

**Anyone know how to overcome this?**

Thanks

Comment: You need to specify a public property with `{ get; set; }` for it to be included during serialization.

Comment: Duplicate of [Newtonsoft deserialize object that extends from Collection<Item>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38665852) (which explains why Json.NET can either serialize collection properties or items, but not both) and [How do I get json.net to serialize members of a class deriving from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21265629).

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado thanks for the comment, though, JSON.NET knows it can call a constructor with fields from JSON, therefore it'll call my `public MyModel(string id)` constructor with a valid `id`

Comment: @dbc thanks, i was searching for "IEnumerable" and missed those entries...
I'll vote duplicate my question :)