# Is there a way to get XmlSerializer (or DataContractSerializer) to serialise the property of an observable object?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

When I run the xmlserializer on my class, it does not output the property I have specified for my nested observable collection. I have made sure it is public and have ensured it has a setter but it just isn't getting serialised.

Running the xmlserializer produces this:

```xml
<ArrayOfArrayOfNote>
  <ArrayOfNote>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
  <ArrayOfNote>
  <ArrayOfNote>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
  <ArrayOfNote>
</ArrayOfArrayOfNote>
```

When I am expecting it to produce something like this:

```xml
<ArrayOfArrayOfNote>
  <ArrayOfNote>
    <Title>SomeTitle</Title>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
  <ArrayOfNote>
  <ArrayOfNote>
    <Title>SomeTitle</Title>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
    <Note>
     (Many Properties of Note)
    </Note>
  <ArrayOfNote>
</ArrayOfArrayOfNote>
```

This is the code I am using for the xmlserializer (which I believe isn't the problem)

```cs
XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NoteBookList));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Notes.xml");
serialiser.Serialize(writer, modules);
writer.Close();
```

This is the class that is not serialized as I am expecting

```cs
[Serializable]
public class NoteBook : ObservableCollection<Note>
{
    public NoteBook()
    {

    }
    public NoteBook(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no way to get both the properties and the contents for any .Net XML serializer only via attributes.  You will need to replace the collection with a surrogate.  See: [XmlSerialize a custom collection with an Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377486).  Theoretically you could implement `IXmlSerializable` but I don't recommend it; see e,g, [How to serialize an `ICollection<T>` that also has read/write properties to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247035).

Answer (score 0):

You class Notes needs to look like this :

```
    public class Notes
    {
        [XmlArray("ArrayOfArrayOfNote")]
        [XmlArrayItem("ArrayOfNote")]
        public NoteBook[] noteBook { get; set; } 

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```