# C# XmlElement Twice the same element

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

I am currently developing a module to generate an XML file.

As a graduate at the instantiation of a list, my tag appears twice at the beginning (operation_unitaire)

```
<compte_type>DROITS_SUSPENDUS</compte_type>
  <stock_epuise>0</stock_epuise>
  <operations_unitaires>
    <operation_unitaire>
      <operation_unitaire>
        <categorie_operation>SORTIE</categorie_operation>
        <date_operation>2016-02-24T00:00:00</date_operation>
        <produit>
          <code_bivb />
          <millesime>0</millesime>
          <degre_alcoolique>0</degre_alcoolique>
        </produit>
        <type_operation />
        <type_justificatif />
        <reference_justificatif>HB024227</reference_justificatif>
        <conditionnement />
        <volume>900.00000</volume>
      </operation_unitaire>
      <operation_unitaire>
        <categorie_operation>SORTIE</categorie_operation>
        <date_operation>2016-02-23T00:00:00</date_operation>
        <produit>
          <code_bivb />
          <millesime>0</millesime>
          <degre_alcoolique>0</degre_alcoolique>
        </produit>
        <type_operation />
        <type_justificatif />
        <reference_justificatif>HB024200</reference_justificatif>
        <conditionnement />
        <volume>900.00000</volume>
      </operation_unitaire>
    </operation_unitaire>
</operations_unitaires>
```

We have the list named operation_unitaires which normally contains the object operation_unitaire

**MODEL operations_unitaires**

```
 [DataContract]
public class operations_unitaires : ISerializable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "operation_unitaire", Order = 1, IsNullable = true, Type = typeof(List<operation_unitaire>))]
    [DataMember(Name = "operation_unitaire", Order = 1, IsRequired = false)]
    public List<operation_unitaire> operation_unitaire { get; set; } //0..n

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public operations_unitaires()
    {

    }
}
```

**MODEL operations_unitaire**

```
 [DataContract]
public class operation_unitaire : ISerializable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "categorie_operation", Order = 1, IsNullable = false, Type = typeof(string))]
    [DataMember(Name = "categorie_operation", Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public string categorie_operation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "date_operation", Order = 2, IsNullable = false, Type = typeof(DateTime))]
    [DataMember(Name = "date_operation", Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    public DateTime date_operation { get; set; }
```

[...]

Has anyone ever had the problem ?

**UPDATE 1**

If I try to rename the name of the object , operation_unitaire to operation_unitairess

```
 [DataContract]
public class operations_unitaires : ISerializable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "operation_unitairess", Order = 1, IsNullable = true, Type = typeof(List<operation_unitaire>))]
    [DataMember(Name = "operation_unitairess", Order = 1, IsRequired = false)]
    public List<operation_unitaire> Operation_unitaire { get; set; } //0..n
```

and i have this result

```
 <compte_type>DROITS_SUSPENDUS</compte_type>
  <stock_epuise>0</stock_epuise>
  <operations_unitaires>
    <operation_unitairess>
      <operation_unitaire>
        <categorie_operation>SORTIE</categorie_operation>
        <date_operation>2016-02-24T00:00:00</date_operation>
        <produit>
          <code_bivb />
```

[...]

So How to stop this tag (operation_unitairess) ?

Comment: the name of your list is the same as the object, try to keep them different, also you should read up on C# coding style.

Comment: i'm trying some tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a hierarchical problem

Today i have this

```
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "operations_unitaires", Order = 3, IsNullable = false, Type = typeof(operations_unitaires))]
    [DataMember(Name = "operations_unitaires", Order = 3, IsRequired = false)]
    public operations_unitaires operations_unitaires { get; set; }
```

Who call this model :

```
[DataContract]
public class operations_unitaires : ISerializable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "operation_unitairess", Order = 1, IsNullable = true, Type = typeof(List<operation_unitaire>))]
    [DataMember(Name = "operation_unitairess", Order = 1, IsRequired = false)]
    public List<operation_unitaire> operation_unitairess { get; set; } //0..n
```

Who call object

```
[DataContract]
public class operation_unitaire : ISerializable
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "categorie_operation", Order = 1, IsNullable = false, Type = typeof(string))]
    [DataMember(Name = "categorie_operation", Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    public string categorie_operation { get; set; }
```

So it's logical, just call the object list directly from the first model !

Answer (score 0):

The tag is not appearing twice.

```
<compte_type>DROITS_SUSPENDUS</compte_type>
  <stock_epuise>0</stock_epuise>
  <operations_unitaires>  <!-- your class operations_unitaires -->
    <operation_unitaire>  <!-- your collection of operation_unitaire -->
      <operation_unitaire> <!-- an instance of of operation_unitaire -->
        <categorie_operation>SORTIE</categorie_operation>
        <...>
```

"We have the list named operation_unitaires"
(this is not the name of your list).

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "operation_unitaire", Order = 1, IsNullable = true, Type = typeof(List<operation_unitaire>))]
[DataMember(Name = "operation_unitaire", Order = 1, IsRequired = false)]
public List<operation_unitaire> operation_unitaire { get; set; } //0..n
```

then name of your list is 'operation_unitaire'.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you mean. So how do you make this tag not appear? Maybe [XmlIgnore] ?

Comment: I wouldn't try and do anything fancy with the tags - best to keep the XML describing the code as close as possible.  If you really have to change the XML, then you might want to consider [implementing IXmlSerializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279534/proper-way-to-implement-ixmlserializable) but that's a bit more advanced.