# How to Serialize List<T> property in c# without showing its type in XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization

I have a class for which I need to serialize it in XML. Below is the example:

```
public class StringArray
{        
    public List<string> Days { get; set; }

    public StringArray()
    {
        List<string> s = new List<string>();
        s.Add("Monday");
        s.Add("Tuesday");
        s.Add("Wed");           
        Days = s;
    }
}
```

When I Serialize it in XML format then result is:

```
 <StringArray xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Days>
     <string>Monday</string>
     <string>Tuesday</string>
     <string>Wed</string>
   </Days>
 </StringArray>
```

However, I need result like below:

```
 <StringArray xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <Days>             
         <Monday />
         <Tuesday />
         <Wed />                 
  </Days>
</StringArray>
```

Actually I do not want to show the type of list item.

Note that the set of possible strings is fixed.  I also tried using an `enum` for this, however the XML shows the `enum` type name instead of 'string' which doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You'll need to handle XML serialization with custom code.

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes? Specifically, `[XmlArrayItem("MemberName")]` .

Comment: Is the set of strings fixed or variable?  For instance, in the example case, it would appear that there should be only seven possible days.

Comment: Yes it is the fixed set of string. I took Enum for this, however it shows enum type instead of 'string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only a fixed set of possible string values, your schema corresponds to an unbounded [sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256089.aspx) of [choice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256109.aspx) elements, where the possible element names correspond to the possible string values.

This can be modeled by replacing the `string` with some appropriate `enum`, then making use of the [Choice Element Binding Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa6z5baz.aspx) support built in to `XmlSerializer`, which requires application of [`XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute.aspx) along with the use of an appropriate serialization surrogate [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

First, define an `enum` that corresponds to the possible string values:

```
public enum Day
{
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
}
```

Next, define the following DTO which will be serialized in place of your `List<Day>`:

```
public class DayListDTO
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public Day [] Days { get; set; }

    [XmlChoiceIdentifier(nameof(DayListDTO.Days))]
    [XmlElement(nameof(Day.Monday), typeof(object))]
    [XmlElement(nameof(Day.Tuesday), typeof(object))]
    [XmlElement(nameof(Day.Wednesday), typeof(object))]
    [XmlElement(nameof(Day.Thursday), typeof(object))]
    [XmlElement(nameof(Day.Friday), typeof(object))]
    [XmlElement(nameof(Day.Saturday), typeof(object))]
    [XmlElement(nameof(Day.Sunday), typeof(object))]
    public object[] DaysObjects
    {
        get
        {
            return Days == null ? null : Enumerable.Repeat(new object(), Days.Length).ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator DayListDTO(List<Day> list)
    {
        return list == null ? null : new DayListDTO { Days = list.ToArray() };
    }

    public static implicit operator List<Day>(DayListDTO dayList)
    {
        return dayList?.Days?.ToList() ?? new List<Day>();
    }
}
```

Finally, make use of the DTO by adding surrogate properties to containing classes as follows:

```
public class StringArray
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Day> Days { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Days")]
    public DayListDTO XmlDaysSurrogate { get { return Days; } set { Days = value; } }
}
```

Which, when serialized, generates the following XML:

```
<StringArray xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Days>
    <Monday />
    <Tuesday />
    <Wednesday />
  </Days>
</StringArray>
```

Notes:

- To use `XmlChoiceIdentifier` correctly with an array, your containing DTO type must have *two* array members:

  1. One array that records the *contents* of the choice elements, here `DayListDTO.DaysObjects`;
  2. One array that records the *names* of the choice elements, here `DayListDTO.Days`, in 1-1 correspondence with the first array.

  Since the elements corresponding to your list of enums contain no contents at all, a dummy array of `object` items is returned for the first array.
- Using `XmlChoiceIdentifier` guarantees that the schema which [`xsd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-def-tool-gen) auto-generates for your types will correctly indicate an unbounded sequence of correctly-named choice elements.  Other solutions such as implementing custom serialization via [`IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279534/3744182) on some subclass of `List<Day>` do not have this advantage.

Working sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RONAvj).

Comment: @RajendraRathore - glad to help.  If the issue is resolved please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147531).

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            List<XElement> strings = doc.Descendants("string").ToList();

            foreach (XElement xelement in strings)
            {
                xelement.ReplaceWith(new XElement((string)xelement));
            }
        }
    }
}
```