# XML Serialization error - Invalid or missing value of the choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' of type 'ItemsChoiceType[]'

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize an object to be passed to a web service and getting the error above. I can see when debugging that the value is present in the object itself but it doesn't seem to be picking this up:

```
string[] tradeAreas = new string[] {"Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Area4"};
//RetrieveMarketResultsFor
ItemsChoiceType[] choices = new ItemsChoiceType[] { ItemsChoiceType.area };
MarketResultIdentifier mri = new MarketResultIdentifier
{
    ItemsElementName = choices,
    Items = tradeAreas,
    ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType6.applyingDate,
    Item = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1)
};

var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MarketResultIdentifier));
using (var stream = new FileStream("mri.xml", FileMode.Create))
    ser.Serialize(stream, mri);
```

The web service generated code has the following classes used in the above code:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3130.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:openaccess")]
public partial class MarketResultIdentifier : OpenAccessAbstractObject {

    private string[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

    private object itemField;

    private ItemChoiceType6 itemElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("area", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("areaNames", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public string[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("applyingDate", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType="date")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("auctionIdentification", typeof(AuctionIdentification))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("deliveryDay", typeof(System.DateTime), DataType="date")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemChoiceType6 ItemElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3130.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:openaccess", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    area,

    /// <remarks/>
    areaNames,
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3130.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:openaccess", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType6 {

    /// <remarks/>
    applyingDate,

    /// <remarks/>
    auctionIdentification,

    /// <remarks/>
    deliveryDay,
}
```

It fails at line when trying ser.serialize....

Any help appreciated :)

**Solution**
Turns out this was just down to me being stupid! Thanks to @dbc for pointing this out. My tradeAreas array had 4 items in there (i was using the wrong array here) which it should have only had one!

Comment: Your question doesn't include the definition and construction of `tradeAreas`, so it doesn't compile.  But if I comment out the initialization of `Items` and `ItemsElementName` then your code works and successfully serializes your `mri` class to XML, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sep6IP.  Can you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: Also can't reproduce if I set up `tradeAreas` as an array of strings with one entry, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/rMTbwh.  Are you sure your `choices` and `tradeAreas` arrays have the same number of items?

Comment: HI @dbc looks like that was it! my tradeAreas array had 4 items in there, when i remove the others and have just one area it is serializing as expected. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: The meta question [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262806) suggests not editing the answer into the question.  You might want to take the solution out and add it as an answer, or accept one of the answers, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute.aspx) to deserialize a sequence of [choice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256109.aspx) elements into some shared data type (here, `string`), you need to add **two** arrays to your data model:

1. A property returning an array of objects of appropriate type to capture the choice element *contents*, here the four string values in the `tradeAreas` array.

   This first array must be marked with `[XmlChoiceIdentifier(name)]` where `name` is the name of the second array, as well as `[XmlElement(elementName)]` attributes for each possible choice element name.
2. And a property returning an array of enums to capture the choice element *names*, here `<area>` for each element.

   This array must be marked with `[XmlIgnore]`.

And finally, since the second array captures the element names for the element contents in the first array, **the arrays must be in 1-1 correspondence**.  Thus `choices` must be initialized to the same length as `tradeAreas`, e.g. as follows:

```
var tradeAreas = new string[] {"Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Area4"};
var choices = Enumerable.Repeat(ItemsChoiceType.area, tradeAreas.Length).ToArray();
```

In your sample code `tradeAreas` has four entries while `choices` has but one, leading to the exception you see.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0uF6WM).

For documentation on binding to XML choice elements using `XmlSerializer`, see [*Choice Element Binding Support: Differentiating by Name*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/sa6z5baz(v=vs.100)#differentiating-by-name) as well as [*XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute Class: Remarks*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxa7ed7e#Remarks).  For a simple manual example, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51681779/3744182) to *[How to Serialize List<T> property in c# without showing its type in XML serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51621320/3744182)*.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this! much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You posted code works provided you add following :

```
    string[] tradeAreas = null;

    public class AuctionIdentification
    {
    }
    public class OpenAccessAbstractObject
    {
    }
```