# XmlSerializer errors after updating from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

So I recently updated a project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.6 and my XML serialization stopped working. I narrowed it down to a single structure that, I agree, looks weird.

```
[XmlElement("price1", typeof(PriceBonusData))]
[XmlElement("price2", typeof(PriceBonusData))]
public List<PriceBonusData> PriceBonusDataList;
```

The error says that I need to add `XmlChoiceIdentifier` attribute to this field, but no matter how I add it, it still doesn't work. What seems strange is that it did work on .NET 3.5, so why the sudden need for new attribute?

Edit: here is my attempt to use XmlChoiceIdentifier. I saw similar solutions both in documentation and on SO, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = false)]
[XmlIgnore]
public ItemChoiceType[] ItemTypeArray = (ItemChoiceType[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(ItemChoiceType));

[XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemTypeArray")]
[XmlElement("price1", typeof(PriceBonusData))]
[XmlElement("price2", typeof(PriceBonusData))]
public List<PriceBonusData> PriceBonusDataList;

[XmlType(IncludeInSchema = false)]
public enum ItemChoiceType
{
    [XmlEnum("price1")]
    price1,
    [XmlEnum("price2")]
    price2
}
```

Edit2: I run some further tests on an empty project with .NET 3.5 version so I figured I could share how this behaves when this works.

This structure is serialized using last XmlElement (in this case "price2").

During deserialization both elements are valid. I manually changed XML file so it contains both "price1" and "price2" and it deserializes them correctly.

Comment: What would it do in 3.5? How would it choose between 1 and 2?

Comment: what would it serialize for a list with a `PriceBonusData` in it? a `<price1>`, `<price2>`? both?

Comment: @GSerg I actually have no idea. It's a legacy code that I had nothing to do with, I'm just getting into the project. I'm not even sure if it's serialized, right now I'm trying to deserialize xml with this structure.

Comment: I'm a little surprised this ever worked.  If you do choose to go the `XmlChoiceIdentifier` route, some options for doing it can be found in [Xml Deserialization - Merging two elements into a single `List<T>` object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37307203/3744182) and [XML Serialization error - Invalid or missing value of the choice identifier `'ItemsElementName'` of type `'ItemsChoiceType[]'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51783203/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

If you're only trying to deserialize, then maybe this will work for you:

```
public class Foo
{
    // the "real" list that takes <price1> elements
    [XmlElement("price1", typeof(PriceBonusData))]
    public List<PriceBonusData> PriceBonusDataList {get;} = new List<PriceBonusData>();

    // spoof a second list that handles <price2> elements (actually: the same list)
    [XmlElement("price2", typeof(PriceBonusData))]
    public List<PriceBonusData> PriceBonusDataList2 => PriceBonusDataList;

    // this disables serialization of PriceBonusDataList2 so we don't double up
    public bool ShouldSerializePriceBonusDataList2() => false;
}
```

The downside is that if you *serialize* it, everything will become `<price1>`, regardless of whether it started as a `<price1>` or `<price2>`... but... I can't see any way around that, since there's nowhere to store what it was originally.

Comment: The main problem with any solution that requires writing seperate collections for different element is that I shortened this example. In code this List has 37 XmlElement tags.

Also I would really like to know why it did work in previous .NET version

Comment: @WojtekPojda ouch... ok, let me have a look at alternatives a sec... (but: it works!)

Comment: @WojtekPojda I *also* can't get `[XmlChoiceIdentifier]` working for this scenario; I *suspect* you've wandered into something that was working by accident, but was not intended as a supported scenario; my suggestion: use reflection to output 36 * the fake list trick as per above, and shove it in a `partial class` somewhere out of the way...

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this is the only explanation. Still, I will keep some hope and wait, maybe someone comes in with an explanation. If not I will mark your as an answer, because it's probably the best solution in this case