# How to serialize into XmlChoice

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xsd.exe, system.xml

I have generated C# classes using xsd.exe from [existing xsd schema](https://express.tnt.com/expresswebservices-website/xsd/tracking/TrackRequest-v3.1.xsd). It generated following property:

```
public class TrackRequestSearchCriteria {

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ConsignmentNumber", typeof(string))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PieceReference", typeof(string))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
public object[] Items {
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

The expected xml is:

```
<SearchCriteria>
    <ConsignmentNumber>#1</ConsignmentNumber>
</SearchCriteria>
```

How do I initialize the `Items` property, so that it serializes into `<ConsignmentNumber>#1</ConsignmentNumber>`?

```
new SomeRootElement {
   Items = new Object[] {
      // how to add ConsignmentNumber here
   }
}
```

@AlexanderPetrov

Comment: Somewhere in your `TrackRequestSearchCriteria` there must be a property named `ItemsElementName`.  Can you please [edit] your question to include it?  Probably related: [XML Serialization error - Invalid or missing value of the choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' of type `'ItemsChoiceType[]'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51786060/3744182).  And actually, that may be a duplicate.  Take a look and let me know.

Comment: new SomeRootElement {
   Items = new Object[] { "#1" }

Comment: dbc: you are right, there is ItemsElementName. I've just reposted this question so that @AlexanderPetrov can answer, because he anwsered it is a question that was closed and never reopened

Comment: You need to set the enumeration :  private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

Comment: @Liero - Stack exchange [doesn't have a messaging system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/431) so if you think adding `@AlexanderPetrov` to your question will message him, then it won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used xsd.exe to generate a set of classes according to the presented scheme.

The following code gives the desired xml.

```
var trackRequest = new TrackRequest
{
    SearchCriteria = new TrackRequestSearchCriteria
    {
        Items = new object[] { "#1" }, // new string[]
        ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType[] { ItemsChoiceType.ConsignmentNumber }
    }
};
 
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TrackRequest));
xs.Serialize(Console.Out, trackRequest);
```