# .NET Core API Input XML deserialize to Model without a wrapper class

Tags: c#, xml, api, .net-core

I have a .NET Core API which accepts the XML as Input and it has a complex type and my Model is having a simple property for that, on deserialization API is giving error.
Sample XML is

```
<Message>
   <EffectiveDate>
      <Date>11/13/2020</Date>
   </EffectiveDate>
</Message>
```

and the Model looks like

```
  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Message")]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Date")]
        public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there any way to handle this without creating the EffectiveDate wrapper class like

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Message")]
    public class MyClass
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "EffectiveDate")]
        public EffectiveDate EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "EffectiveDate")]
    public class EffectiveDate
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Date")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? I can not change the XML since it is coming from some other application and there are many elements wrapped like this so looking for a way to have Model without an extra wrapper class

Comment: you can create a cstom xml serializer.

Comment: The controller you set the starting point in the Xml file.

Comment: You could [implement `IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279534/3744182) for `MyClass` but honestly that would be more work than creating the wrapper class.