# Recursive XML Deserializes Incorrectly

Tags: c#, xml, linq, recursion, deserialization

( See [this demo](https://rextester.com/IFLD6822) for more details )

Suppose I have an XML file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Container>
  <SomeValue>1</SomeValue>
  <Item>
    <Containers>
      <Container>
        <SomeValue>2</SomeValue>
          <Item>
            <!-- etc... -->
          </Item>
      </Container>
      <Container>
        <SomeValue>3</SomeValue>
      </Container>
    </Containers>
  </Item>
</Container>
```

where the class called `Container` contains a single `Item` and the class called `Item` can have many sub-containers.

The `Container` class implements `IXmlSerializable` (see notes for why), and it has the following method:

```cs
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load(reader.ReadSubtree());
    this.SomeValue = (int)root.Element("SomeValue");

    XElement itemElt = root.Element("Item");
    if (itemElt == null)
    {
        // Empty container
        return;
    }

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));
    using (var itemReader = itemElt.CreateReader())
    {
        this.Item = (Item)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(itemReader);
    }
}
```

However, running this results in the root container's item only containing the first container (where SomeValue is 2) even though there is more than 1 container in its `Containers` node.

**So why are the other containers being skipped and how could I fix it?**

I'm assuming it's an issue with the call to `ReadSubtree()` but leaving this out gives me:

```
InvalidOperationException: The XmlReader state should be EndOfFile after this operation.
```

---

#### Some Notes:

The reason I have to use `IXmlSerializable` is because the actual "Item" type is fetched from a database depending on the the element's name. So when I call `new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item))`, I'm actually calling `new XmlSerializer(specificItemType)`.

Additionally, I would prefer to do as much as I can with `System.Xml.Linq` since it's very readable (and I'm pretty new to XML stuff). It also allows me to get data from anywhere in the tree without having to re-read the whole document, which I do a bit in my actual code. However, if it must go then I'm willing to part with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that this:

```cs
XElement root = XElement.Load(reader.ReadSubtree());
```

Leaves the reader at the end of the element (i.e. `</Container>`). The contract for `IXmlSerializable.ReadXml` is that you must 'read' this too, leaving the reader at the beginning of the next element. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280077/1320845) helps to clarify that.

So the fix is to add another `reader.Read()` call before returning. I've updated [your demo](https://rextester.com/IDIF51056):

```
===Input===
Container {1} - Item: [ Container {2} - null, Container {3} - null ] (2)

===Output===
Container {1} - Item: [ Container {2} - null, Container {3} - null ] (2)
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!