# Serializing ArrayList outputs ArrayOfAnyType

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I do have a problem with serializing a ArrayList. Most propably I use wrong XML Attributes for it since I when I changed them it would not even serialize it and got errors like 'The type may not be used in this context.'

I need to use a non generic ArrayList. On adding [XmlArray("LineDetails")] made this code to run but the output is not correct, it should give me the LineDetails structure. Any idea how to fix this?

This is a part of a whole xml like Document > Header > LineCollection > LineDeatails.
The problem is only with this details if I use a standard string field it is ok but the range of the colletion if changing with every document.

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "LineCollection")]
public class LineCollection
{
    public String LineCount{ get; set; }          
  //  [XmlElement(ElementName = "LineDetails")]
    [XmlArray("LineDetails")]
    public ArrayList LineDetails{ get; set; } 
}
public class LineDetails: ArrayList 
{
    public String LineNum{ get; set; } 
    public String ItemId{ get; set; } 
    public String ItemName{ get; set; } 
    //... only strings
}

public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding => new UTF8Encoding(false);
}

public string Serialize()
{
    // var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    var xmlserializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(LineDetails) });
    var Utf8StringWriter = new Utf8StringWriter();
    var xns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    xns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(Utf8StringWriter))
    {
        xmlserializer.Serialize(writer, this, xns);
        return Utf8StringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

And the incorrect output of this...

```
<LineColletion>
    <LineDetails>
        <anyType xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="ArrayOfAnyType"/>
        <anyType xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="ArrayOfAnyType"/>
        <anyType xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="ArrayOfAnyType"/>
    </LineDetails>
</LineColletion>
```

it should be like this

```
<LineColletion>
    <LineDetails>
        <LineNum>1</LineNum>
        <ItemId>Item_2321</ItemId>
        <ItemName>TheItemName</ItemName>
    </LineDetails>
    <LineDetails>
        <LineNum>2</LineNum>
        <ItemId>Item_232100000</ItemId>
        <ItemName>TheItemName0</ItemName>
    </LineDetails>
    <LineDetails>
        <LineNum>3</LineNum>
        <ItemId>Item_23217777</ItemId>
        <ItemName>TheItemName7</ItemName>
    </LineDetails>
</LineColletion>
```

Now the wrong xml looks like this...

```
  <LineDetails>
        <anyType xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="LineDetails">
            <LineNum>1</LineNum>
            <ItemId>Item_2321</ItemId>
            <ItemName>TheItemName</ItemName>
        </anyType>
        <anyType xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="LineDetails">
            <LineNum>2</LineNum>
            <ItemId>Item_2321</ItemId>
            <ItemName>TheItemName</ItemName>
        </anyType>
    </LineDetails>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _“it should give me the LineDetails structure”_? What _structure_? What is the type(s) of objects you are storing in that `ArrayList` instance? Please provide a [mcve] _including actual data_ and the expected XML.

Comment: I update the question. This is a example structure I have more than 20 strings in Details to return. All data is comming from a different class as a ArrayList and contains only strings.

Comment: Why do you inherit `LineDetails` from `ArrayList`? It makes hardly any sense. Just declare the property as `[XmlElement] public LineDetails LineDetails { get; set; }` and you are done.

Comment: Well... actually I don't remember why I left it like this.. Yet it solved partially the problem. The details are there but under anyType element instead of LineDetails, I will add it in question in a sec.

Comment: So how can I remove this ?  <anyType xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" p5:type="LineDetails">

Comment: *I need to use a non generic ArrayList* -- does that mean you must make `LineDetails` inherit from `ArrayList`, or you merely must use an ArrayList for the property `public ArrayList LineDetails{ get; set; }`?

Comment: If you can change `LineDetails` so that it no longer inherits from `ArrayList` you can your required XML as shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KVbc8i.  But can you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generate the required XML by modifying your data model as follows:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "LineColletion")] // Fixed: TypeName.  But do you want LineColletion (misspelled) or LineCollection (correctly spelled)?  Your XML shows LineColletion but your code used LineCollection.
public class LineCollection 
{
    public String LineCount{ get; set; }          
    [XmlElement("LineDetails", typeof(LineDetails))] // Fixed -- specify type(s) of items in the ArrayList.
    public ArrayList LineDetails{ get; set; } 
}

public class LineDetails // Fixed: removed inheritance from ArrayList.
{
    public String LineNum{ get; set; } 
    public String ItemId{ get; set; } 
    public String ItemName{ get; set; } 
    //... only strings
}
```

Notes:

- Your model makes `LineDetails` inherit from `ArrayList`.  `XmlSerializer` will **never** serialize collection properties, it will only serialize collection **items**. In order to serialize it correctly, I removed the inheritance since you don't seem to be using it anyway.

  If you really need `LineDetails` to inherit from `ArrayList`, you will need to [implement `IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279534) or replace it collection with a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

  Implementing `IXmlSerializable` is tedious and error-prone. I don't recommend it.
- Your `LineDetails` collection is serialized without an outer wrapper element.  To make the serializer do this, apply [`XmlElementAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute) to the property.
- `ArrayList` is an untyped collection, so you must inform `XmlSerializer` of the possible types it might contain.  You have two options:

  1. Assigning a specific type to a specific element name by setting [`XmlElementAttribute.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.type) (or [`XmlArrayItemAttribute.Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.type)), OR
  2. Adding [`xsi:type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ca1ks327(v=vs.100)) attributes by informing the serializer of additional [included types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute).  You are doing this by passing them into the constructor, which is why you are seeing the `p5:type="LineDetails"` attribute.

  Since you don't want the attributes, you need to set the element name by setting the type like so:

  ```
  [XmlElement("LineDetails", typeof(LineDetails))]
  ```
- The XML element corresponding to your `LineCollection` is named **`<LineColletion>`**.  Note that the spelling is inconsistent.  You will need to set `[XmlType(TypeName = "LineColletion")]` to the name you actually want.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KVbc8i).